# How to apply the search intent filter and android.app.searchable to all activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, searchview, android-searchmanager

I have quite a few activities in my android app and need to implement an ActionBar with a SearchView.

I initially just added the following lines to my SearchActivity:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
  </activity>
```

However, `searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());` returned `null` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` when invoked from `AnotherActivity1`.

So I also added the `intent-filter` and `android.app.searchable` meta-data to `AnotherActivity1` and that works for the `AnotherActivity1` SearchView.

But I have many such activities - am I supposed to just copy-paste this XML snippet for all of them or is there some more elegant solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I think I figured it out myself.

Use

```
searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class));
```

instead of

```
searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
```

Then I have to apply the `intent-filter` and `meta-data` only to `SearchActivity`.